# 7zip command not extracting to specified output directory

Tags: windows, command-line, 7-zip

```
7z x d:\migration\mongo\mongodb.7z o:f:\data *.* -r
```

I'm using this command as part of a batch to extract the contents of a 7z file from one drive (D) to another (F). The folder structure is important so I'm using the `x` command with recursion.

What's supposed to happen is the archive contents are decompressed into `f:\data`.

What's *actually happening* is the contents are being decompressed into the batch file's directory working directory (`f:\migration\`). Specifying working directory (`-w:`) in the command has no effect.

How can I make my command work as intended?

I'm using 7zip x64 9.22b on Windows Server 2012 R2.

Edit: my original question noted that data was being extracted to two simultaneous places. As it turns out this was not the case. My question was updated to reflect this.

Comment: After the completion of the extraction you have 2 full archive items or was one location being used as the "temps" ?   What happens if you specify a working folder too? -W

Comment: What OS is this in? there are other things that seem odd about the command shown.  "o: " (with a colon there)  The documentation shows like " -oF:Data ", then why the wildcard on extract, when your trying to extract all?   I don't know myself but for winders OS it did not seem logical.

Comment: I'm using Windows Server 2012 R2. After completion I have two full copies. `-o:` is the argument for specifying the output directory (`-o{dir_path}`), and from the documentation I've seen the slash is necessary. As for the wildcard, without it no files are extracted for some reason.

Comment: I haven't tried specifying a working directory. That's a good idea, I'll give that a try.

Comment: Since it's not extracting to two places, you should edit the question title as well to reflect the actual problem.

Comment: -oOutpuutDirectory only works during extraction, it seems to be ignored during archiving.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I'm using 7za.exe (command line version) but the same holds true for 7z.exe. Take a look at the help message *carefully*:

```
7-Zip (A) 9.20  Copyright (c) 1999-2010 Igor Pavlov  2010-11-18

Usage: 7za <command> [<switches>...] <archive_name> [<file_names>...]
       [<@listfiles...>]

<Commands>
  a: Add files to archive
  b: Benchmark
  d: Delete files from archive
  e: Extract files from archive (without using directory names)
  l: List contents of archive
  t: Test integrity of archive
  u: Update files to archive
  x: eXtract files with full paths

<Switches>
  -ai[r[-|0]]{@listfile|!wildcard}: Include archives
  -ax[r[-|0]]{@listfile|!wildcard}: eXclude archives
  -bd: Disable percentage indicator
  -i[r[-|0]]{@listfile|!wildcard}: Include filenames
  -m{Parameters}: set compression Method
  -o{Directory}: set Output directory
  -p{Password}: set Password
  -r[-|0]: Recurse subdirectories
  -scs{UTF-8 | WIN | DOS}: set charset for list files
  -sfx[{name}]: Create SFX archive
  -si[{name}]: read data from stdin
  -slt: show technical information for l (List) command
  -so: write data to stdout
  -ssc[-]: set sensitive case mode
  -ssw: compress shared files
  -t{Type}: Set type of archive
  -u[-][p#][q#][r#][x#][y#][z#][!newArchiveName]: Update options
  -v{Size}[b|k|m|g]: Create volumes
  -w[{path}]: assign Work directory. Empty path means a temporary directory
  -x[r[-|0]]]{@listfile|!wildcard}: eXclude filenames
  -y: assume Yes on all queries
```

You see how it's clearly mentioned that the switches are `-o` and `-w`? As in, there's a **hyphen** preceding the switches but not the commands. Also, the **colon** is *not* part of the switch itself. If it was, then you should have similarly used `x:` instead of just `x` for extracting with paths. Consequently, your weird usage of `o:<Path>` and `w:<Path>` is the reason for your headaches.

Use something like this to compress a folder recursively and store relative paths:

```
7za a -r Archive.7z C:\InputFolder
```

Use the following to extract to a specific directory:

```
7za x -oD:\OutputFolder Archive.7z
```

Obviously if your folder names have spaces in them use double quotes.

Comment: I have been using 7zip for years, and still get tripped up on the commandline parameters every now and then. Very well written answer @Karan

Answer (score 1):

In my case, it was working in CMD, but not in Powershell. Quoting the destination directory solved it for me.

The following works in CMD, but not Powershell

```
7z x d:\migration\mongo\mongodb.7z -of:\data *.* -r
```

The following works in both

```
7z x d:\migration\mongo\mongodb.7z -o"f:\data" *.* -r
```