# 7zip force archive download via command line

Tags: windows, command-line, batch-file, 7-zip

I Have searched here, stackoverflow and 7zip docs without finding a clear answer. I am wondering:

Can I use 7zip via command line (actually using .bat file) and force archive to download via prompt?

My .bat file looks like this:

```
7z.exe a mathtest.zip finalmathtest\*
```

If this is not possible, how about sending to a users desktop? This could be an alternative for my needs.

Thanks for all input.

Comment: Perhaps the reason you don't get any decent answers is because your question does not make sense.  "7z a mathtest.zip finalmathtest" will include the "finalmathtest" directory and all of its files and subdirectories.  What does "downloading" have anything to do with this?  Downloading involves copying files over a network.  We can't really give you the instructions that will let you do whatever it is that you are trying to do, because we don't understand what you are trying to do.

Comment: Sorry. Trying to make a bat file that is run inside a software which zips the folder "finalmathtest". The folder contains mock math tests that teachers create and will be printed out later. Currently software is opening folder but teachers requested zip file for easy emailing. Guess I am showing my age and not being clear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<Commands>
  a : Add files to archive
  b : Benchmark
  d : Delete files from archive
  e : Extract files from archive (without using directory names)
  h : Calculate hash values for files
  i : Show information about supported formats
  l : List contents of archive
  rn : Rename files in archive
  t : Test integrity of archive
  u : Update files to archive
  x : eXtract files with full paths

<Switches>
  -- : Stop switches parsing
  -ai[r[-|0]]{@listfile|!wildcard} : Include archives
  -ax[r[-|0]]{@listfile|!wildcard} : eXclude archives
  -ao{a|s|t|u} : set Overwrite mode
  -an : disable archive_name field
  -bb[0-3] : set output log level
  -bd : disable progress indicator
  -bs{o|e|p}{0|1|2} : set output stream for output/error/progress line
  -bt : show execution time statistics
  -i[r[-|0]]{@listfile|!wildcard} : Include filenames
  -m{Parameters} : set compression Method
    -mmt[N] : set number of CPU threads
  -o{Directory} : set Output directory
  -p{Password} : set Password
  -r[-|0] : Recurse subdirectories
  -sa{a|e|s} : set Archive name mode
  -scc{UTF-8|WIN|DOS} : set charset for for console input/output
  -scs{UTF-8|UTF-16LE|UTF-16BE|WIN|DOS|{id}} : set charset for list files
  -scrc[CRC32|CRC64|SHA1|SHA256|*] : set hash function for x, e, h commands
  -sdel : delete files after compression
  -seml[.] : send archive by email
  -sfx[{name}] : Create SFX archive
  -si[{name}] : read data from stdin
  -slp : set Large Pages mode
  -slt : show technical information for l (List) command
  -snh : store hard links as links
  -snl : store symbolic links as links
  -sni : store NT security information
  -sns[-] : store NTFS alternate streams
  -so : write data to stdout
  -spd : disable wildcard matching for file names
  -spe : eliminate duplication of root folder for extract command
  -spf : use fully qualified file paths
  -ssc[-] : set sensitive case mode
  -ssw : compress shared files
  -stl : set archive timestamp from the most recently modified file
  -stm{HexMask} : set CPU thread affinity mask (hexadecimal number)
  -stx{Type} : exclude archive type
  -t{Type} : Set type of archive
  -u[-][p#][q#][r#][x#][y#][z#][!newArchiveName] : Update options
  -v{Size}[b|k|m|g] : Create volumes
  -w[{path}] : assign Work directory. Empty path means a temporary directory
  -x[r[-|0]]{@listfile|!wildcard} : eXclude filenames
  -y : assume Yes on all queries
```

Comment: Thanks. Got all the commands and have read https://www.dotnetperls.com/7-zip-examples but not getting anywhere. Was hoping for example.

Comment: use full path ok?

Comment: Take it there is no way to force download and ask user where to save zip. So guess best solution is send zip to users desktop. Just can't figure that one out. Looking at http://superuser.com/questions/914084/7zip-command-not-extracting-to-specified-output-directory and still confused.

Comment: prompt path in cmd file and pipe to  -o{Directory} : set Output directory

Comment: Thanks Tony, I will try and figure out how to use the -o{Directory} within my .bat file. Your input much appreciated.

Comment: How does this actually answer the question? You could have at least guided the OP towards which option to use ...

Comment: I offered the options not avail by >  7z.exe /?   Assumption is OP already knows how to make batch file with %1 variables... or can find out how similiar batch files work within user interface not defined (prompts and persistent saves in .inf file or registry. feel free to make a batch file with this input, that is too big as a comment